# The Frobenius Automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If a finite field $F$ has characteristic $p$, prove that every element $a\in F$ can be expressed as $a=b^{p}$ for some $b\in F$?

Hint: Frobenius Automorphism.

Isn't the Frob Automorphism about $a$? Why does it have to do with $b$?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your first paragraph does not make sense, really. In every field, independently of its characteristic, and for all integer $p$, it is the case that «$a=b^p$ for some $a\in F$ and $b\in F$». What you wrote is probably not what you wanted to ask. (I wonder what question people are answering...)

Answer (score 2):

If you say Frobenius "Automorphism" then you should be done...

If you just want to say Frobenius  map then,

Hint :

- Prove that map is injective
- any injective map between two finite sets of same cardinality is ???

Comment: Why am I done? Isn't the Frobenius Automorphism about mapping $a$ to $a^{p}$? What does it have to do with $b$?

Comment: what is an automorphism by the way?

Comment: I still don't understand...

Comment: It is a ring homomorphism mapping to itself and is bijective?

Comment: do you see ring homomorphism and field homomorphism to be same??

Comment: didn't learn field homomorphism...

Comment: ok.. As you said it is at least a bijetive... in particular surjective...  $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if given $y\in Y$ i have $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$... Can you see what would surjectivity  of frobenious map $f :F\rightarrow F$ with $f(x)=x^p$ imply?

Comment: So am I set to say: For all $a \in F$, there is a $b \in F$ so that $f(b)=b^{p}=a$?

Comment: yes....$~~~~~~$

Comment: okay... I guess I was just confusing myself earlier...

Comment: So, I guess you are clear with this now!

Answer (score 0):

The Frobenius map is just a map: $$\phi: F \rightarrow F$$
where $\phi(a) = a^p$ and char($F$) $=$ $p$

So if you know what an automorphism is, it just follows.

Comment: Negative! For saying automorphism, he should prove what he is asked to....

Comment: @Mark I am actually supposed to prove that $a=b^{p}$ if char($F$)=$p$... Would you elaborate on why it just follows from the definition of an automorphism? Thanks!

Comment: An automorphism is an isomorphism onto itself, it's a bijective map. Of course, you're supposed to prove it. :P

Comment: @Mark And what am I supposed to do after proving it is bijective? That still doesn't solve the $b^{p}$ issue... Isn't it supposed to be $a^{p}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructive reason; it's just the pigeonhole principle. The Frobenius map is injective since the polynomial $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$, so since it acts on a finite set, it must be surjective.

Note that there can be no constructive reason, since there exist non-perfect fields: those for which the Frobenius map is not surjective. An example is $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, where by degree, $t$ is not a value of the Frobenius map.

Answer (score 0):

Supppose that $F=\mathbb F_{q}$ where $q=p^r$ for some positive integer $r$, then elements of $F$ will be the roots of the polynomial $x^q-x$. Thus for every $a\in F$ we have $a=a^q=a^{p^r}=\left(a^{p^{r-1}}\right)^p$, so $b=a^{p^{r-1}}$ is the required solution such that $a=b^p$.